# Fortran: What exactly is .d0?

Tags: fortran

I understand that `.d0` denotes `double precision` however I wonder how it goes together with user defined precision. I use

```
module precision
implicit none
    integer, parameter :: DP = selected_real_kind(r=250,p=13)
end module precision
```

and declare floats as

```
real(KIND=DP) :: var1
```

Whenever I need to assign a value to such a float somewhere in the programme I do

```
var1 = 1_DP
```

Now the problem I have is that it does not work if I read the value from a namelist. The compiler insists on

```
&namelistName
    var1 = 1.d0
    !var1 = 1_DP   ! this does not work
&end
```

Two questions follow:

1. What happens if I assign value of `1.d0` to a variable declared as `real(KIND=DP)`?
2. Is there a way how to enforce `1_DP` in namelists? If it matters of course.

Comment: You did not write why it doesn't work. In fact this phrase alnost always means you should iclude something more, error message or anything. `1_dp` is an integer.

Comment: Wait a minute, `1_DP` is an integer?! Ups, really? OK forget question 2 for now. What about question 1? If I do `1.d0` what am I doing actually? I will check the compiler message meanwhile.

Comment: This still active thread may also help you understand the details https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.lang.fortran/IoI5Mes2Se4[101-125-false]

Comment: @VladimirF Many thanks I have started reading it and it looks very informative.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The whole concept of kinds makes sense only in the source code, there is no way making it work for input data, because at runtime the system knows nothing about them.

In the source code

```
  1.d0
```

is a double precision real,

```
  1._dp
```

is a real with kind `dp`,

```
  1_dp
```

is an integer (no decimal there) with kind `dp`.

In the input data you don't need to specify the precision at all, you just need a number. The runtime system then converts the string with a number to the right type of variable you are trying to read.

You can use `1.e0`, `1.d0`, as an extension maybe even `1.q0`, just to be flexible, but it doesn't change the meaning. In the input file it is just a string representing a number.

What happens, if you in the source code assign

`real(dp) :: x = 1.d0` ?

It is just simply assigned if the `dp` kind is the same kind as the double precision. Otherwise it is converted. If the real constant value is a small integer, the conversion is simple and no precision is lost as they are represented exactly.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation this is exactly what I needed. So my mistake was not to distinguish between `1_DP` and `1._DP`. I have always been doing this in the source code but then the compiler must have converted the integer to a float so that I never noticed the difference. Although somewhere I have read that `1_DP` would be converted to a `single precision` only (can't find it now). Hence I have inadvertently fallen into this trap.

Comment: Regarding your question "`real(dp) :: x = 1._d0`?" when I do `x = 1_DP`, `x = 1._DP` or `x = 1.d0` it compiles. Doing `x = 1._d0` actually doesn't. Interestingly doing `x = 1._DP` in the namelist file does not work either but I have not seen the error message yet I can only say it returns non-zero status and segfaults consequently. However from you answer I gather that `x = 1.d0` in namelist is fine and won't lose me any precision.

Comment: Even 1 should be fine. Or 1.0. The runtime system doesn't understand the suffix in the namelist and cannot convert it to a number.

Comment: Sorry the `1._d0` was an error, it should be `1.0d0` or `1.d0`. Also i like `e` better then `d` in data files, but that is a style thing.